# C++ inline assembly looping through 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly

So i have a homework where i have to take 1 2d array loop through it, do some calculations and output it in a different array. But i am pretty much stuck, i can not figure out how to loop from the first array and assign the elements to the second one. In the code below i can not change the input parameters ( since this is a homework ). The function has to accept pointers to both arrays. I think i have looping through first array handled ( i am not entirely positive, it might be wrong ), and main problem is assigning to the second array. I am not doing any calculations to the element when looping as the first important thing is actually making the loop and assignment to the second array work.

Function:

```
//To reach each element of the 2D array, i am using this formula: 
    // base + itemsize*rowsize*rowoffset + itemsize*itemoffset
// i got it from this video ( time 2:06 to see it ) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBor-6kiavI

// For each grade level variant implement own function, e.g.:
void solution_for_grade_7(const int * arr, size_t arr_rows, size_t arr_cols, int * result)
{
    //Calculate the sum of positive values for each row.
    __asm
    {
        // Your Inline Assembler instructions for grade X level go here
        // :::
        mov esi, arr
        mov ebx, result
        mov ecx, [arr_rows] ; loop at rows
outer:  push ecx ; loop stuff

        mov ecx, [arr_cols] ; loop at each element of row ( aka. eadch column of row )
inner:  push ecx ; loop stuff

        mov ebx, [esi]  ; i think the error is here
        add ebx, 4
        add esi, 4

        pop ecx ; loop stuff
        loop inner

        pop ecx ; loop stuff
        loop outer ; loop stuff
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
const size_t ROWS = 2;
const size_t COLS = 3;

int main()
{
    // Change the array definitions and/or values to demonstrate your variant:
    int data1[ROWS][COLS] = { { 0, -1, 2 }, { 3, 4, -5 } };
    //int result1[ROWS]; // Note: for some variants the result array size depends on the COLS! 
int result1[ROWS*COLS];
    // Change the parameters according to your assignment function, e.g.:
    solution_for_grade_7((const int *)data1, ROWS, COLS, result1);

    // Print the result values to the console:
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < ROWS; i++)
        printf("%d ", result1[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // Add another input array definitions and/or values to demonstrate your variant:
    // :::

    // Examples of passing invalid arguments (must not fail for grade 10):
    // solution_for_grade_X((const int *)data1, ROWS, 0, 0);
    // solution_for_grade_X(0, 0, COLS, result1);
    // :::

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should almost *never* write inline ASM. Let the compiler generate that from readable C++ code.

Comment: It is a task requirement, i can only change inline assembly inside function. And I can call that function inside Main. Other from that, I cannot change, according to the requirements.

Comment: So you have to write the loop through the 2d array in assembly and the assignment in legacy c++ code? Is there a "why in asm"? What is the exact/full assignment? If I would have to do that I would write the code in c++ and check the debugger/compiler what its doing in assembly and just copy that out since c++ is just translating the code to asm. I like that stuff and would post you a correct answer :)

Comment: Bruh.  I can not change anything outside inline assembly and main function. If it was up to me i would not even do this in c++ put down assembly.

Comment: Full task is adding all of the negative numbers on rows of const int * arr and putting the results inside int * result

Comment: You eventually need code written in asm, but you can *look at what a compiler does* for code written in C++, to help you write your own version of that in asm.  That's what Ivanovic was saying.  Looking at (partially-optimized) compiler output is often a helpful starting-point.